# MailMessage & MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN

Tags: vb.net

I was told that my program was not issuing a MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN when sending an email by the web hosting company we are connecting to.

Anyone know what this means and how I do it?

I am sending an email with SmtpClient and I have no problems with other clients.

Here is what I was told:

> Thanks for the additional info, here
>   is what I found...
>
> Aug  4 11:16:48 smtp1 sendmail[2729]:
>   o74GGU5F002729:
>   xx-xx-xx-xx.static.xxx.mo.charter.com
>   [xx.xx.xx.xx] did not issue
>   MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection
>   to TLSMTA
>
> Notice the time and the IP address
>   which is your static from Charter. Now
>   here is a good connection.
>
> Aug  4 11:18:22 smtp1 sendmail[2745]:
>   STARTTLS=server,
>   relay=xx.xx.xx.xx.static.xxx.mo.charter.com [xx.xx.xx.xx], version=TLSv1/SSLv3,
>   verify=NO, cipher=RC4-MD5,
>   bits=128/128 Aug  4 11:18:23 smtp1
>   sendmail[2745]: AUTH=server,
>   relay=xx.xx.xx.xx.static.stls.mo.charter.com
>   [xx.xx.xx.xx], authid=ronmid,
>   mech=LOGIN, bits=0
>
> Since their email program did not
>   issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during
>   connection, my server would not
>   continue the transaction.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You app didn't issue any of those 4 commands after connecting. This could be because the server didn't respond correctly and so your app was waiting for that response until it timed out. You can check this by trying to send an email with a simple telnet connection as described [here](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html). After you connect and send the EHLO or HELO command (depending on what the server wants) you should get a 250 response.

If you do get the 250 response with telnet but your app still doesn't work, then maybe it's something in your application that tries to send an incorrect command. Maybe you've setup your application to use SSL or credentials, and the SMTP server don't support that or something similar?